# PHP program to connect to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, connection

I've been doing a project in PHP(xampp) which requires to connect to a SQL Server database.

I've already done things like downloading and installing `SQLSRV30.exe` in `C:\xampp\php\ext` folder and creating a simple program which determine whether the program is already connected or not but still couldn't figure it out the problem that i encountered.

```
$server = "IDEA-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$dbGet = array("Database"=>"LogboxDB");
$con = sqlsrv_connect($server, $dbGet) or die (sqlsrv_error());
if(!$con)
{
     die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else
{
    echo 'Connected';
}
```

Here is my error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect();

How can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the extension support to use the MSSQL server in PHP. It can be enabled by editing the php.ini as follow.

extension=php_sqlsrv.dll

You can donwload the package from http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-admin/howto-installing-sqlsrv

Comment: well thank for your answer.
I've already tried that solution but it doesn't give me the right approach my problem.
Sir could you give me more solutions and ways to find it out.
Thanks Sir

Comment: Please confirm from phpinfo pages that mssql extension loaded and visible in phpinfo page. iF yes then please connect it using.

  `$link = mssql_connect("127.0.0.1:64900", "username", "test") or die ( "ERROR: Connection MSSQL server". mssql_get_last_message());`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$serverName = "192.168.1.223, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName - change it as yours

// Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"LogboxDB", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks delvin paul.but still it says the same error.
 Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()